How do I establish a real-time connection between a Laravel backend and React Native Expo frontend?
I'm working a Laravel and React Native project where real-time communication is crucial. In scenario where a user updates their profile other users should get the update in real time. And a chatting functionality to be integrated as well.
Currently, I'm using Laravel & Reverb on the backend. I installed socket.io-client on the RN Expo app but the connection is never established.
Don't know why that is though. I need help on how to integrate this correctly.
